# PHP echo problem

Tags: php, mysql

```php
$today = date('D, d M, Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs 
        WHERE day1 = '$today' OR day2 = '$today' OR day3 = '$today' OR day4 = '$today' 
        OR day5 = '$today' OR day6 = '$today' OR day7 = '$today' OR day8 = '$today' 
        OR day9 = '$today' OR day10 = '$today'";
if($_POST != "") {
  $mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
  if($mydate != "") {   
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM programs 
         WHERE day1 = '$mydate' OR day2 = '$mydate' OR day3 = '$mydate' OR day4 = '$mydate' 
           OR day5 = '$mydate' OR day6 = '$mydate' OR day7 = '$mydate' OR day8 = '$mydate' 
           OR day9 = '$mydate' OR day10 = '$mydate'";
  }
}
```

`$mydate` is incorporated with a calendar....

How I php echo the date?

Comment: May be worth a mention that you forgot to close double quotes on **line 2**.

Comment: Perhaps it's also time to read a little something about [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), it's almost never a good idea to have numbered columns in a table; that reeks of denormalisation, which generally makes your life a lot harder.

Answer (score 5):

Your `$mydate` is automatically converted by php if you use double quotes: you just missed a double quote at the end of the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE day1 = '$mydate' OR day2 = '$mydate' OR day3 = '$mydate' OR day4 = '$mydate' OR day5 = '$mydate' OR day6 = '$mydate' OR day7 = '$mydate' OR day8 = '$mydate' OR day9 = '$mydate' OR day10 = '$mydate'";//Missing double quotes
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot " in sql query.

```
$today = date('D, d M, Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE day1 = '$today' OR day2 = '$today' OR day3 = '$today' OR day4 = '$today' OR day5 = '$today' OR day6 = '$today' OR day7 = '$today' OR day8 = '$today' OR day9 = '$today' OR day10 = '$today'";

if($_POST!=""){
$mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
    if($mydate!=""){    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE day1 = '$mydate' OR day2 = '$mydate' OR day3 = '$mydate' OR day4 = '$mydate' OR day5 = '$mydate' OR day6 = '$mydate' OR day7 = '$mydate' OR day8 = '$mydate' OR day9 = '$mydate' OR day10 = '$mydate'";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use double quotes it should belike this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE day1 = '$mydate' OR day2 = '$mydate' OR day3 = '$mydate' OR day4 = '$mydate' OR day5 = '$mydate' OR day6 = '$mydate' OR day7 = '$mydate' OR day8 = '$mydate' OR day9 = '$mydate' OR day10 = '$mydate'";`